# \ gets inserted in Alamofire request

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

My request in going with \ inserted into it.

**Note -**
 I want to send **JSON object** to the server as parameter.

```
     let param : Parameters = ["SessionBean":["billId": self.SessionListArray[row].billId, "memberId": self.SessionListArray[row].memberId,"SessionConductId":self.SessionListArray[row].sessionConductId ]]

 Alamofire.request(URL2, method: .get, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.prettyPrinted).debugLog().responseString { response in
            print("Success:Session: \(response.result.isSuccess)")
            print("Result...\(String(describing: response.value))")

            if(response.result.isSuccess) {
                if(response.value != nil){

                }
            }
            if(response.result.isFailure){
                print("Failure\(response.result.isFailure)")
            }


        }
```

This is my request output. The \ is causing **HTTP Status 500 - Read timed out**.

```
 {
          \"SessionBean\" : {
            \"SessionId\" : \"3\",
            \"memberId\" : \"8\",
            \"billId\" : \"55\"
          }
        }" \
```

Comment: no, it does not, that is just the representation of `"` inside Strings.

Comment: @luk2302 It's escaping the double quotes right?

Comment: @Wez yes, but **only** for displaying purposes, not for transmission.

Comment: so are you saying my request is not the problem @luk2302

Comment: I'd say that `JSONEncoding.prettyPrinted` could be the issue. I clearly don't know why `prettyPrinted` should be used, it adds spaces/new lines just to be "pretty".

Comment: I used JSONEncoding.default also, but I got the same error.

Comment: How do you know it's your `This is my request output`? Shouldn't this be inside the URL since you are doing a GET method? something like `myURL?q=SessionBeanetc.`?

Answer (score 0):

Try **JSONEncoding.default** instead of **JSONEncoding.prettyPrinted**

Also, try replacing **.responseString** with **.responseJSON**